# Automatic generation of equidistant points inside a polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to find a way to generate a layer of points inside a given polygon of, for instance, 100 m x 600 m. Every points must be at least 20 meters away from the others and from the polygon borders, and the polygon must contain the maximum amount of points.

Comment: Did you try Vector-> Research tools -> Regular points?

Comment: I don't know the correct answer but, unfortunately, 'Regular Points' will only provide the maximum amount of points if the polygon in question happens to fall on the optimal axis (i.e. not tilted).

Comment: I know ArcGIS has a "fishnet" tool, but again I suspect that's only if it lines up with rectangular axes.

Comment: Something like this, maybe? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/333822/122597

Comment: Thanks for the input Stefan. My question was a longtime ago but the problematic exposed in your link is pretty close to what I was trying to do ("max amount of points inside the polygon" apart, from what I understand.)